# Chaining Multiple USB Hub Controllers for Serial Interfacing

Tags: usb, serial, usb-device, usb-host, serial-bus

I have a need for a large amount of serial I/O from a desktop computer in a robotics application. I considered using all off the shelf parts with a large set of USB hubs and usb to serial adapters, but off the shelf solutions were too large.

I need about 26ish, maybe more channels running anywhere from 9600 to 115200baud. To fit in the tight space I was considering getting some USB hub controllers, and putting them on a circuit board with the usb to serial ASICs.

The host computer is a mini itx intel based machine.

My current concept involves this 4 channel USB 3 hub controller:
[4 Port USB 3 Hub](http://www.ti.com/product/tusb8041-q1)
And several 7 port USB 2 hub chips:
[7 Port USB 2 Hub](http://www.ti.com/product/tusb2077a)
[image: concept]
The 7 port hubs would be connected to the super speed 4 port hub ports, thus giving all the USB endpoints I need. The USB to serial ASICs (FTDI or similar product) would be directly connected to each 7 port hub controller port. I know that FTDI for instance offers multi channel usb to serial devices, but I don't know if each USB channel enumerates as a separate device in linux (as in a seperate /dev/usbttyx device)

My questions is, how difficult is this hardware to implement? I've done some differential signal design before, but never USB speed fast. I was also considering having separate control of the power to each hub controller so they could be separately reset if needed.

Are there any traps I need to watch out for specific to working with these USB chips? This will be my first board design that has USB on it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is usually solved not with USB but with a "fieldbus", this is why things like CAN were developed. A straightforward solution is RS485 with a single master, which you can daisy chain no problem (just respect termination), there is no reason to use 28 seperate serial host controllers

Comment: If you want to use, USB, what you propose should work. AFAIK, USB has a limit of 127 devices, including hubs, so you should be within the limit. Each should instantiate as a /dev/ttyUSB device, though you may not have any control on which device is which number. In fact, this may change from power-up to power-up!

Comment: @DoxyLover no problem to assign the same tty number based on serial id (if it is provided) or alternatively based on physical port number using UDev

Comment: @crasic The devices all use different types of serial interface. Not something I have control over. Some are RS485, 422, 232, and TTL. Although having a bunch of CAN devices sounds significantly less terrible. Part of what pushed me away from CAN is the cost of the interface devices is somewhat higher...But if it's simpler it might be worth it.

Also, how would I go about assigning the tty numbers to overcome the issue DoxyLover pointed out?

Comment: @alphasierra any field bus will require something equivalent to your FTDI chip for USB, CAN is heavier on peripherals, but there are other systems to choose from (ethernet based ones for instance). USB will absolutely work, but you may have requirements that it will not satisfy, deterministic response time and network polling for instance.

Comment: Have you considered using a serial server? A typical serial server will give you 8-32 ports of 232/422/485, connected to the network via TCP sockets. Size-wise, a 32-port serial server can be had in 1RU.

Comment: @crasic is right, you can set up udev rules to map specific units to ttyUSB numbers. This takes fairly advanced Linux udev knowledge.

Comment: @DoxyLover: How complicated are we talking? Is it extremely convoluted?

Comment: @uint128_t I considered that however I only need to run asynchronous serial protocols for the most part. Also those servers tend to have the bulky db9 connectors on them. I'm looking for something cheap, compact, with terminal blocks.

Comment: @crasic That's a good point...I'll need to look into it. Part of the motivation for this approach was it would be super simple from a software standpoint, and this is meant for a student project. The idea being that they could just call an existing serial device. But if we can make it easy to address messages over CAN then it seems like the better solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about asynchronicity, 232/422/485 are asynchronous. The serial servers that I am familiar with actually have RJ45 termination, so it is very easy to build your own cables, and the connectors are relatively compact. However, they aren't _super_ cheap, but $1500 for 32 configurable serial channels isn't a bad deal.

Comment: I would cal udev moderately complicated. Basically, you need to write rules based on some criteria to assign specific device names. Hopefully, each serial dongle will report a unique serial number on which you can key. I'm not really qualified to come up with more details. Suggest you search the net for "udev rules".

Comment: One potential drawback I see is power distribution; some downstream ports may need to be self-powered (i.e. the root port may not be able to supply all the power necessary from its USB port).

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, I just can't comment...

Did you evaluate the option to use simple Arduino/AVR? With Atmega128 TQFP64 you should be able to get 26ish software serials, the hardware UARTs can go as fast as 2Mbps (to connect to PC host), Atmega128 has 2.

There is also STM32F103 series ARM with 72MHz clock.

On the PC host side, if you really need 26 separate COMs, there is possibility to use [virtual COM ports](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/)...some software will be needed to "aggregate" data of these 26 ports into real 1. Or edit your PC software. Creating some custom protocol (similar to Modbus) to address each serial port shouldn't be hard. Same on MCU side.